# `psfragtrans` and parentheses

Tags: eps, psfrag, translate

I have the following string in eps-file

```
(\(actual)S
```

I need to insert an appropriate element into tex-file to translate it. I tried

```
\psfragtrans{(actual}{(фактичні}
```

But this doesn't work. I got the following:

```
Error: /syntaxerror in -file-
Operand stack:
   --dict:83/200(L)--   true
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1999   1   3   %oparray_pop   1998   1   3   %oparray_pop   1982   1   3   %oparray_pop   1868   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1212/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:83/200(L)--   --dict:139/300(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 1396862
GPL Ghostscript 9.21: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Comment: Full minimal example please. If possible please also provide the EPS. Where does `psfragtrans` come from? If is not listed in `psfrag`.

Comment: possibly `\string\(actual` would work, but without an example, hard to say

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, sir! It works! Maybe you would like to transfer it to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

psfrag doesn't do PS-escaping of special PostScript characters so you need to use `\string\(actual` as the search text so you are passing in the literal PostScript `\(actual` which, as you show, is how the string appears in the EPS file.